# Smoothness of integral along fibers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Let $\pi:M\rightarrow N$ be a holomorphic function between complex manifolds such that each fiber $M_s(s\in N)$ is compact and $\dim M_s=\dim M-\dim N$. Let $d=\dim M-\dim N$. Let $\omega$ be a $d$-form on $M$, and $f$ be a smooth function on $M$. Consider the following function
$$(s\in N)\mapsto \int_{x\in M_s}f(x)d\omega$$
where by abuse of notation, we still denote by $\omega$ its restriction on $M_s$. Is this function smooth as well?

Comment: To integrate $\omega$ (or this, times a function) only over a fiber, you need it to have the correct degree ($\dim{M}-\dim{N}$ in best-behaved settings), so it can’t be a volume form. If I understood correctly, perhaps a better phrasing is as follows: let $f: M \rightarrow N$ be a holomorphic map with compact fibers of constant dimension $d$. Let $\omega$ be a $d$-form, is $s \in N \longmapsto \int_{M_s}{\omega}$ smooth?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked for natural additional assumptions that make the result true?